# expect statement in bash script for error validation of expected output

Tags: bash, expect

I have the following expect statement within my bash script:

```
/usr/bin/expect << EOF
spawn -noecho lucli users add -username user -role admin -email 
user@user.com
expect "password:" { send "password\n" }
expect "password:" { send "password\n" }
expect eof
EOF
```

I want the expect script to validate that the correct output is returned from the CLI command after it passes the passwords and creates the user.

The message I want to validate that gets returned is "added to the system successfully"

I can't figure out how to do that from within the bash script using expect.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `expect` here at all, rather than passing a pre-`crypt`ed copy of the password on the command line? Expect isn't part of bash -- it's a completely separate programming language derived from TCL, and is otherwise a big hammer to pull in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
# note the quoted here-doc word
status=$(/usr/bin/expect << 'EOF'
    spawn -noecho lucli users add -username user -role admin -email 
    user@user.com
    expect "password:" { send "password\r" }
    expect "password:" { send "password\r" }
    expect eof
    set status [string match "*added to the system successfully*" $expect_out(buffer)]
    # $status will be the C-like boolean 0 or 1
    exit $status
EOF
)
if [[ $status -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "user added OK"
else
    echo "user not added"
fi
```

ref: https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm